# How get duplicate on all keys from table

Tags: sql, teradata

I have below query and by using that i can find out duplicates on particular
keys. I have 335 columns in table so query will be bigger if mention all column names in the query

```
select stone_id,charge_title,count(*) from table group by stone_id,charge_title having count(*) > 1
```

But i want to find out duplicates on all keys from table by better way.
Please suggest solution

Comment: how are they keys if they have duplicates?. Also, mySQL or teradata?

Comment: You might take a look at OpenRefine ... it's an analysis tool first created by some folks at Google.  https://github.com/OpenRefine

Comment: I removed the MySQL tag then. In the future, use only relevant tags on your question please

Comment: What's wrong with the way you're using now?